# Get selected value of option with multiple dropdown menus using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a form which has multiple drop down menus and I have one of my drop down menus working fine which when selected shows another drop down, using the following code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js">        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("name");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".building").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".building").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
</script>
```

My issue here is that further down the page I have more drop downs which seem to be impacted by this code.  Is there a way I can stop the jQuery running against all forms on the page?

Comment: Instead of adding a change function for all dropdowns using "$("select").", access the controls using a class

Comment: I think this error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" says that there is some missing JS files that should be added.

Comment: Isn't this because jQuery isn't imported? - edited my post to reflect this.